# Writing DAX expression with multiple IF conditions (Excel to DAX-Power BI)

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have this formula in Excel and I need it rewritten in DAX but I am unsure how to do this. I am very very new to DAX and so far have only been able to do the basics. I hope someone can help!

Excel Formula:

```
=IF([@[Date Shipped]]="","",IF([@[Date Exchanged]]="",[@[Date Shipped]]-[@[Date Approved]]+1,[@[Date Shipped]]-[@[Date Exchanged]]+1)-([@[Paused Days (Total)]]*([@[Paused Days (Total)]]<>"")))
```

My attempt with DAX, disastrous and clearly not correct:

```
Column = IF(ISBLANK('winnipeg erp_workorder'[Date Shipped]),BLANK(),IF(ISBLANK('winnipeg erp_workorder'[Date Exchanged]),('winnipeg erp_workorder'[Date Shipped]-'winnipeg erp_workorder'[Date Approved])+1),('winnipeg erp_workorder'[Date Shipped]-'winnipeg erp_workorder'[Date Exchanged])+1)-(IF(NOT(ISBLANK('winnipeg erp_workorder'[Paused Days Total],'winnipeg erp_workorder'[Paused Days Total]*'winnipeg erp_workorder'[Paused Days Total]))))
```

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Carla

Comment: It's  a bad idea trying to translate Excel formulas into DAX - these are conceptually very different languages and direct translation is often impossible. Instead, post your data model diagram, provide a data sample, and describe an example of the desired results. You will get help easier and better.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to provide exact solution without having the PBIX file because in DAX we have Measures and Columns so at the moment I am only guessing that everything that you have inside the code is coming from the columns.

You can use this and modify it to get to the desired result:

```
Column =
VAR DateShipped = 'winnipeg erp_workorder'[Date Shipped]
VAR DateExchanged = 'winnipeg erp_workorder'[Date Exchanged]
VAR DateApproved = 'winnipeg erp_workorder'[Date Approved]
VAR PausedDaysTotal = 'winnipeg erp_workorder'[Paused Days (Total)]
VAR Result =
    IF (
        NOT ISBLANK ( DateShipped ),
        IF (
            ISBLANK ( DateExchanged ),
            DateShipped - DateApproved + 1,
            DateShipped - DateExchanged + 1 - PausedDaysTotal
        )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

Thank you,

Antriksh Sharma

Comment: Unfortunately this did not seem to work, I got an error: DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Date with values of type Text. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values.... Nothing is formatted as Text, all are Dates except Paused Days Total which is whole numbers. Any ideas?

Comment: @CarlaDawn You can use ISBLANK, I have edited my answer.